# Accuracy is dropped after adding a dense layer to a pretrained Mobilenet model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have the following code, utilising mobilenetv2 for two class classification. After adding the dense layer with 2 units, the accuracy is dropped significantly to 45%. I couldn't figure out what could be the issue, I changed optimiser but still accuracy didnt improve. My training dataset is 2000 with two categories, cat and dog.

```
custom= MobileNetV2(input_shape=None,
                   alpha=1.0,
                   include_top=True,
                   weights='imagenet',     
                   input_tensor=None,
                   pooling=None,
                   classes=1000,
                   classifier_activation='softmax')
   x= custom.output
   final_output=layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(x)
   model = keras.Model(inputs=custom.input, outputs = final_output)
   for layer in custom.layers:
     layer.trainable = False

   model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='BinaryCrossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],loss_weights=0.1)
```

Comment: You are putting a classifier on top of another classifier, no wonder it performs bad.

Comment: what @Dr.Snoopy said. and to be precise. You have a classifier with 1000-size output and softmax activation and on top of that you add another layer. What you should you , you should replace the last layer with the new layer or simply use the classes argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `include_top=False` statement when you load the pretrained model. This code statement removes the last part of the pretrained model.